# Removing NA in correlation matrix

Tags: r, variables, matrix, correlation, na

I am doing a correlation matrix for a dataframe of 4000 variable and I would like to remove the variables showing > 0.5 correlation, so I am using this command from the {caret} package.

```
removeme <- findCorrelation(corrMatrix, cutoff = 0.5, verbose = FALSE)

Error in if (mean(x[i, -i]) > mean(x[-j, j])) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The data I have is highly variable, and I get NA values here and there. To start with, I couldn't find something that can deal with NA values on the help page of this command, so I decided to remove the NA values myself.

Some variables show NA values all the way across the data, and some show few NA values. I am trying to remove the variables that are causing any NA values, so that I would be able to use the above command. Here's a minimal example of what my data looks like

```
dput(df) <- structure(list(GK = 1:10, HGF = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), HJI = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    HDF = c(5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), KLJG = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), KLJA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), KDA = c(10L, 11L, 15L, 18L, 
    11L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 12L, 13L), OIE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AFE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("GK", "HGF", "HJI", "HDF", "KLJG", 
"KLJA", "KDA", "OIE", "AFE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

corrMatrix <- cor(df,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

What would be the best idea to get rid of these annoying variables? I have tried Many commands but did not get to an ideal one that would get rid of these variables. Here are one of my trials:

```
removeme <- corrMatrix[,which(as.numeric(rowSums(is.na(corrMatrix))) > 100)]
```

The issue with this command that if there was over a 100 faulty variables (giving NA in correlation matrix) the normal variables will be removed, as the columns of the normal variable will have > 100 NA values.

I hope this edit made my question more clear. Cheers.

Comment: Please post a sample of your `corrMatrix` .  If there are `NA` values in the matrix, then you need to decide what you want to put there, e.g. zeroes or an artificial large value, to allow `findCorrelation` to complete its task.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you simply want to get rid of any column that has one or more `NA`s, then just do

```
x<-x[,colSums(is.na(x))==0]
```

However, even with missing data, you can compute a correlation matrix with no `NA` values by specifying the `use` parameter in the function `cor`.  Setting it to either `pairwise.complete.obs` or `complete.obs` will result in a correlation matrix with no `NA`s.

`complete.obs` will ignore all rows with missing data, whereas `pairwise.complete.obs` will just ignore the missing pairs of data.  Note that, although `pairwise.complete.obs` "sounds better" because it uses more of the available data, but it isn't guaranteed to produce a positive-definite correlation matrix, which could be a problem.

```
> set.seed(123)
> x<-array(rnorm(500),c(100,5))
> x[sample(500,3)]<-NA
> cor(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]    1   NA   NA          NA          NA
[2,]   NA    1   NA          NA          NA
[3,]   NA   NA    1          NA          NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA  1.00000000 -0.01925986
[5,]   NA   NA   NA -0.01925986  1.00000000
> cor(x,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  1.00000000 -0.04377085 -0.18049501 -0.04914247 -0.19374986
[2,] -0.04377085  1.00000000  0.01296008  0.02606083 -0.12333765
[3,] -0.18049501  0.01296008  1.00000000 -0.03218139 -0.02675554
[4,] -0.04914247  0.02606083 -0.03218139  1.00000000 -0.01925986
[5,] -0.19374986 -0.12333765 -0.02675554 -0.01925986  1.00000000
> cor(x,use="complete.obs")
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  1.00000000 -0.06263112 -0.17914810 -0.02574970 -0.20504268
[2,] -0.06263112  1.00000000  0.01263764  0.02543900 -0.12571570
[3,] -0.17914810  0.01263764  1.00000000 -0.03866312 -0.02520500
[4,] -0.02574970  0.02543900 -0.03866312  1.00000000 -0.01688848
[5,] -0.20504268 -0.12571570 -0.02520500 -0.01688848  1.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am actually doing a pairwise correlation, but I have many variables giving NA all the way, or sometimes in part. Can you please have a look at the comment I have just added under my command in the question? there is the main issue!

Comment: What's wrong with setting `df<-df[,colSums(!is.na(df))>0]` to get rid of columns that are all `NA` before generating the correlation matrix?

Comment: Because I am not entirely sure only the "all-zero" variables are causing the NA (thought there might be something else, as I am working with thousands of variables. Anyway I am trying it now. Hope it will work. thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yes only the all-zero columns turned out to make the problem, this is embarrassing! I am not sure if I should keep the question, might be useful for someone?

Comment: My dataset have no NA values, however when I compute the correlation matrix, the correlation matrix itself produces some NA values. How do we prevent this happening in the first place? How do we prevent correlation matrix to produce NA values? @mrip

Answer (score 6):

Before evaluating the correlation for predictors of your dataset remove the zero variance predictors.

#### to remove zero variance predictors

```
zv <- apply(df, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)

dfr <- df[, !zv](suppose df is the name of your dataset)

n=length(colnames(dfr))
```

## calculate correlation matrix

```
correlationMatrix <- cor(dfr[,1:n],use="complete.obs")
```

## summarize the correlation matrix

```
print(correlationMatrix)
```

## find attributes that are highly corrected (ideally >0.7)

```
highlyCorrelated <- findCorrelation(correlationMatrix, cutoff=(0.7),verbose = FALSE)
```

## print indexes of highly correlated attributes

```
print(highlyCorrelated)
```

### important variables

```
important_var=colnames(df[,-highlyCorrelated])
```

Comment: Why is it important to remove zero variance predictors, please?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what are you trying to do. But here an example in how to deal with missing values. I show this in a small matrix.

```
mm <- matrix(NA+0,ncol=4,nrow=3)
mm[1:3] <- 1
mm[8] <- 1

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1   NA    1   NA
[3,]    1   NA   NA   NA
```

#### remove columns with all elements are NA

```
mm[,!colSums(is.na(mm)) == nrow(mm),drop=FALSE]
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   NA
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1   NA
```

#### remove columns having any NA

```
mm[, !colSums(is.na(mm)) >1,drop=FALSE] ## you can also complete.cases
    [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1
```

Comment: The problem why I cannot drop columns this simply is because the correlation matrix is a symmetrical matrix, so any NA showing in 1 variable, means it is going to be repeated all over the matrix. For this reason, if I do a `na.omit()` I loose some of the variables I actually want. Can you please have a look at the example I have just added? Thanks

Comment: @Error404- you ever find a solution? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: My dataset have no NA values, however when I compute the correlation matrix, the correlation matrix itself produces some NA values. How do we prevent this happening in the first place? How do we prevent correlation matrix to produce NA values? @agstudy